# Java-Metro, from glassfish server side, i do not succeed in forcing client ssl certificate to be sent?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, glassfish, jax-ws

i want my webclient to be forced to send a ssl certificate during SSLTransaction establishment.
I do not succeed in configuring my webservices application (metro jax-ws + glassfish) to have it done. (i check using openssl that 'No client certificate CA names sent' by server )

My web.xml contains:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SSL constraint</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>INTEGRAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

My keystore.jks, and cacerts.jks contains aliases xws-security-client and xws-security-server with correct certificate.

Where are my errors or miss  ? How i can debug ?

i just want both side ssl authentication.(client/server)

Answer (score 0):

To help,
My miss was that i forgot to tick the box 'Client Authentication Enabled' in:
admin glassfish->Configurations->server-config->HTTP Service->Http Listeners-> http-listeners-2